# Seeing over the borders

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I am working on a `ScrollViewer` in **Expression Blend** right now.
Some of the controls within that `ScrollViewer` are out of the borders of that template phone image, which is always on Blend.

How can I see Silverlight controls outside that border? I would like to see everything on Blend, not just what the user can see. I am particularly talking of `TextBlocks`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `d:DesignHeight="2000"` of `phone:PhoneApplicationPage` and `Height` of `LayoutRoot`: `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="2000">`. It's not a clean solution but maybe it somehow helps.